# how can I use function map for data frame in sparkR?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I have a data frame as shown below

```
ozone particullate_matter carbon_monoxide sulfure_dioxide nitrogen_dioxide
1   101                  94              49              44               87
2   106                  97              48              47               86
3   107                  95              49              42               85
4   103                  90              51              44               87
5   105                  94              49              39               82
6   106                  92              48              42               77
```

How can i find  correlation between the columns in sparkR.

Answer (score 1):

You can't at the moment, but you will be able to do so in SparkR 1.6, which is coming out any day now. See this [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10752)

Comment: I'll save you the effort of following the link.  Indeed the issue is marked 'resolved'.